# linear regression with a transformed dependent variable

Tags: regression

Can I use log function with base 10 instead of the natural log in order to transform a dependent variable in a linear regression? By using log we can fix the violation of the normality assumption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the base of the logarithm is equivalent to a [factor in the outcome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base). Specifically in your case
$$
\log_{10}(y) = \frac{1}{\ln(10)} \ln(y).
$$
It therefore doesn't make a difference for linear regression, except that the regression slope(s) will change by the same factor.